# Pass data from NSViewController to another NSWindowController

Tags: swift, xcode, appkit, nsviewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

I'd like to have data inputted from one view controller (with its own window controller) be passed along (only one way) to another window controller with its own view controller. The reason I'd like to pass it specifically to the window controller is because I have a toolbar on the window controller. I've used passing data using segues between view controllers, but when I try to pass to a window controller, the data does not update. Here is `my prepare(for: sender:)` method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let windowController = segue.destinationController as! WindowController
    windowController.test = "hello"
}
```

Where `test` is a variable in my WindowController class. Also, if there is a better way to do this, or a better approach overall, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show how you written test in WindowController?

Comment: do you have multiple segue case ?

Comment: @Jok3r test is defined at the top of my class as such: "var test : String = """

Comment: replace that and try var test : String! and let me know

Comment: @Jok3r Just did that, no change

Comment: do you have multiple segue in the vc ?

Comment: @Jok3r No, just this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222630/discussion-between-camsox-and-jok3r).

Comment: Which object owns the data (app delegate, window, document, a controller, …)? Is the other window an existing window? When do you want to pass the data? Can you pass the data to the other view controller?